# Tips for managing internal and external links using WordPress

Tags: seo, links

So I'm looking for ways to optimize my site for user and search engine purposes.  I've read several articles and looked at several different plugins.  To say the least, I'm thoroughly confused as what are the best practices for managing internal and external links.  Here is a list of some of my questions:

- Which internal links should be set to "nofollow"?
- Which external links should be set to "nofollow"?
- To what degree does actively managing links contribute to your PR?
- Should you use "nofollow" blindly on all links in comments?
- If a link to an external site is broken (404 or whatever), should you "nofollow" that link?  What about "noindex"?

As you can see, lots of questions.  I'm hoping that you experienced webmasters can give a newb some best-practice advice.

Comment: I originally wanted to mark this as an exact duplicate but there's more then one question this is a dupe of. Most, if not all, of these questions have been asked here before. I suggest using the search feature of this website first and reading up on the answers it provides. Then if you have a specific question about something, feel free to ask it here.

Comment: dang, i just signed up and am committing acts of sin! what would be a better question?

Comment: ok, good advice, john, thanks...i was hoping to get an consolidated answer, but i'll try to reconcile all the seemingly conflicting advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. Google changes too frequently to spend hours sculpting, and page rank is a minimal part of their ranking these days.

Get the page descriptions and meta tags right and then concentrate on good, relevant content and link internally when it's good for the article - this is what will get people to link to you.